# Yearling badges being given too often

Tags: bug, badges

I've gotten the yearly badge 4 times in the last few months:

- 7 hours ago
- Jul 15 at 22:06
- Jun 10 at 22:37
- May 6 at 23:26

I think the problem is that I was largely inactive for several years and so did not earn the required 200 reputation and therefore no badge. Since the spring I have earned the required 200 reputation to catch up for the years I didn't do much and the calculation appears to be confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. Per the SE Meta [answer for participation badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#188731) ***List of all badges with full descriptions***:

> #### Yearling
>
> - silver; awarded multiple times
> - Have a reputation of at least (number of years since registration) × 200 + 1 (starting reputation)
>
>   - The number of years is not restricted to integers and increases continuously. For example, if at the 2-year mark you don’t have the
>       400 required reputation, the number of years still continues to
>       increase. So half way through year 3 (i.e., after 2.5 years), you’d
>       need 2.5 × 200 = 500 reputation to qualify for the second yearling
>       badge.
>   - If at any point you qualify for this year’s badge, you will receive all badges you had previously missed up until this year
>       whenever the script runs again.
>   - The badge used to require only (years) × 100 reputation; this was [changed after the account association bonus was
>       implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32626)

Since your account is 5 years old, breaking the 1K mark has awarded you this year's badge as well as the previous 4 years.